# Data exchange between UIViewControllers, Service and Views

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, model-view-controller

Top brick problem I face every time is a passing data between component.

I can separate this problem in few sub-problems:

1. Do we need to pass data to views? Do we need to change model directly in view?
2. Can we use some service call directly from views, or we need to pass back all operation to `UIViewConrtoller` and only then controller will request appropriate service.
3. Specifying indexes instead of real models.

So the first question demonstrate case when we create UITableViewCell and pass to it data directly. So we now have ability to modify some properties of this data object. Let's say we have `PlayListViewController` that implement `UITableView` datasource. If you see bellow I set data model directly into view.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
  {
    let cell = viewController.theTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(String(SongTableViewCell.self)) as! SongTableViewCell
    cell.song = songs[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }
```

Second one for example, when you want to trigger something in your service directly from your `SongTableViewCell` without using any delegate calls. Let's say in `SongTableViewCell` I want to play my song and on this cell I have play button. So then it is a simple solution - I can bind cell with UIButton action `touch up inside` for example and invoke needed operation in my service:

```
@IBAction func onTappedPlayButton(sender: AnyObject)
{
    MusicService.playSong(song)
}
```

But usually I do another things. I store delegate instance in my cell that pass back any action to a controller and controller decides what to do:

```
@IBAction func onTappedPlayButton(sender: AnyObject)
{
   delegate?.didTappedPlayButton()
}
```

In this case `SongTableViewCell` looks like this:

```
class SongTableViewCell: UITabeViewCell
{
  weak var delegate:SongTableViewCellDelegate?
  ...
  @IBAction func onTappedPlayButton(sender: AnyObject)
  {
       delegate?.didTappedPlayButton(index)
  }
}
```

and my view controller implements this `didTappedPlayButton` method where it calls `MusicService.playSong(song)`. Here is 3rd problem if we have not pushed model object into `UITableviewCell` then we need to say somehow to view controller that it needs to play some appropriate song from array. So I use index that I set into the `UITableviewCell` which is sometimes can tangle other developers. I don't know if it's better to use index or data model. I understood advantage of changeability but `index` say nothing for developers and data model object says a lot.

I know it's more architecture questions, but maybe we can outline some props and cons of these 3 approaches/problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [post](http://krakendev.io/blog/subclassing-can-suck-and-heres-why) and it says

Classes=more complexity. Values=less complexity. Not sure it can fit all my subquestion, but maybe values it much better then transit entire class.